# Slide down menu with multiple parents/children

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I'm trying to do a sort of accordion type menu, where all first level pages are laid out, and if you click a parent page, it'll slideDown and then if you click a page with further child elements, it slides down again.

I'm a little stuck, here is what I have below. Firstly, because the slideDown action is attached to the LI, it slides back up when you try and click a child element which has children too. Is there any way to select the anchor to be clicked and then the   will slide down?

Sorry to be a little confusing with my explanation, but hopefully the HTML and JS so far will help explain. A simple click and expand menu.

**UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/TDPb4/1/**

Thanks,
R

HTML:

```
<ul class="sub-navigation">
  <li class="page_item page-item-29 current_page_item parent"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/">Clinical/Laboratory</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item page-item-40 parent"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/histopathology/">Histopathology</a>
        <ul class="children">
          <li class="page_item page-item-99"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/histopathology/test-page/">Test page</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-42"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/bacteriology/">Bacteriology</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-46"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/packaging-guidelines/">Packaging Guidelines</a></li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-44"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/water-quality-analysis/">Water Quality Analysis</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item page-item-33 parent"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/education-and-training/">Education and Training</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item page-item-104"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/education-and-training/test-page/">Test page</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item page-item-31"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/environmental-services/">Environmental Services</a></li>
  <li class="page_item page-item-35"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/products/">Products</a></li>
  <li class="page_item page-item-27"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/veterinary/">Veterinary</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".sub-navigation li.parent a").click(function(e) {
   $(this).parent(".children").slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.closest()`  instead of `.parent()`

```
$(".sub-navigation li.parent a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventdefault()
   $(this).closest(".children").slideToggle('fast');
});
```

**UPDATED**

```
$(".sub-navigation li.parent a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   $(this).closest('.parent').find("> .children").slideToggle('fast');
});​
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/TDPb4/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. I've set up a Fiddle to see if this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/TDPb4/1/

The anchor links shouldn't work and act as '#' if the element has children.

Comment: Check the Updated code .. There was  problem with the code that I have written .. We need to find the children inside the parent and then do the Toggle.. Use the Updated code in th epost

Comment: Thanks for this. Quick issue. There's a child element within the top parent that has child elements itself (Test) which is being shown on opening. The slide needs to iterate down to the lowest level. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that

Comment: If you look at the Fiddle you updated, when you click 'Clinical/Laboratory' it's child pages drop down as expected, but 'Test page' is a child page of 'Histopathology' and shouldn't show unless it's clicked. And so on.

Comment: If that's the case change find(".children") to find("> .children") .. I have also updated the post with this  .. The > will only select the immediate children and not all the nested children